# Rotation of the cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I have the following tikzpicture,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed](-3,-3)--(3,3);
\draw[dashed](-3,3)--(3,-3);
\draw(0,0)--(3,0);
\node[cylinder,fill=gray, shape border rotate=180,shift={(2cm,0cm)}, draw, minimum height=0.1cm, minimum width=0.1cm] {};
\node at(1,0.2){\small $r$};
\draw plot[smooth,tension=1]coordinates{(0.3,-0.3)(0.4,-0.15)(0.35,0)};
\node at(0.6,-0.2){\small $\phi$};
\draw[-latex](1.75,0.3)--(2.2,0.3);
\node at(1.975,0.5){\small $v$};
\draw[-latex] plot[smooth,tension=1]coordinates{(3,-0.2)(3.1,0)(3,0.2)};
\node at (3.4,0){\small $\omega$};
\draw(1.5,0)--(1.75,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, I want to rotate this shape but something unusual thing happens.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{scope}[shift = {(1,1)}, rotate = 45]
\draw[dashed](-3,-3)--(3,3);
\draw[dashed](-3,3)--(3,-3);
\draw(0,0)--(3,0);
\node[cylinder,fill=gray, shape border rotate=180,shift={(2cm,0cm)}, draw, minimum height=0.1cm, minimum width=0.1cm] {};
\node at(1,0.2){\small $r$};
\draw plot[smooth,tension=1]coordinates{(0.3,-0.3)(0.4,-0.15)(0.35,0)};
\node at(0.6,-0.2){\small $\phi$};
\draw[-latex](1.75,0.3)--(2.2,0.3);
\node at(1.975,0.5){\small $v$};
\draw[-latex] plot[smooth,tension=1]coordinates{(3,-0.2)(3.1,0)(3,0.2)};
\node at (3.4,0){\small $\omega$};
\draw(1.5,0)--(1.75,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The cylinder remains at the same position. How can i overcome this problem ?
[image]

Comment: Use `\node[cylinder, transform shape, ...] ...` to allow outside transformation.

Comment: Very elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: Just another solution, adding ``[rotate=45]`` to the cylinder line also solves the problem. The full line were then
``\node[rotate=45] [cylinder,fill=gray, shape border rotate=180,shift={(2cm,0cm)}, draw, minimum height=0.1cm, minimum width=0.1cm] {};
\node at(1,0.2){\small $r$};``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt using `transform canvas ={rotate=45}` instead of `rotate=45`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture} 

\path (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\begin{scope}[transform canvas ={rotate=45}]
  \draw[dashed](-3,-3)--(3,3);
  \draw[dashed](-3,3)--(3,-3);
  \draw(0,0)--(3,0);
  \node[cylinder,fill=gray, shape border rotate=180,shift={(2cm,0cm)}, draw, minimum height=0.1cm, minimum width=0.1cm] {};
  \node at(1,0.2){\small $r$};
  \draw plot[smooth,tension=1]coordinates{(0.3,-0.3)(0.4,-0.15)(0.35,0)};
  \node at(0.6,-0.2){\small $\phi$};
  \draw[-latex](1.75,0.3)--(2.2,0.3);
  \node at(1.975,0.5){\small $v$};
  \draw[-latex] plot[smooth,tension=1]coordinates{(3,-0.2)(3.1,0)(3,0.2)};
  \node at (3.4,0){\small $\omega$};
  \draw(1.5,0)--(1.75,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This is also a helpful solution.

Comment: You're welcome!